# What can I use to embed turn by turn map navigation in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dictionary, navigation

I want to embed turn by turn navigation into my flutter app. The solution that I found is flutter_mapbox_navigation, but it seems that has some issues. Is there another alternative?

Comment: You haven't explained what "has some issues" means.  We're not clear whether we can just help you with those issues, or what a different solution would require to not trigger the same issues.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.